# What does the /= operator in Haskell mean?

Tags: haskell

I am reading [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com), which contains `5 /= 5`. I am not so sure what this means. Does the first expression mean `5 / 5 = 5`? But, then, it shouldn't be `True`.

Comment: The opposite of: `==` :)

Comment: Next time use: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: @Rizier123 which gives me `(/=) :: a -> a -> Bool infix 4` which is not very helpful as a beginner....

Comment: @mhutter Have you clicked on the link?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes! Ah, now I see. I didn't see the description above because the browser tab froze so I assumed I was at the top of the page. My bad :)

Comment: "but then it shouldn't be True." It *isn't* True.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It means not equal. So `5 /= 5` is *false* as `5 == 5` is *true*.

`x /= y = not (x == y)`

As suggested, it recalls the mathematical symbol "≠" (/=) opposite to "=" (==).

Comment: It is an equal signed crossed out i.e not equal.

Comment: So the Haskell equivalent of !=

Answer (score 21):

The `==` operator means "is equal".

The `/=` operator means "is *not* equal".

It's supposed to be reminiscent of the mathematical "≠" symbol (i.e., an equals sign with a diagonal line through it).

Answer (score 4):

It's the "not equal to" operator.

Various languages use for example `!=`,`<>`, etc... and Haskell uses `/=` ;)

Using `:t` can tell you the type:

```
> :t (/=)
(/=) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

Comment: Incidentally, the [`Data.Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) module also exports a `<>` operator, which doesn't mean "not equal", but is a synonym of `mappend`.

Comment: Right. Looking at the type we can see it does something completely different: `(<>) :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m`

Comment: super noobie here: how to *read* the output of `:t`  i see `a` three times ;)

Comment: "where type `a` can be tested for equality, operator `/=` takes two arguments of that type and returns a boolean."